# @font-face is not working in IE9 and only IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face

I've been reading all the others who run into this issue and trying exactly what they're saying, but still getting no luck in ie9.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OswaldLight';
    src: url('fonts/oswald-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/oswald-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/oswald-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/oswald-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/oswald-light-webfont.svg#OswaldLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

}

That's in the css.

the site is [dwlawtx.com](http://www.dwlawtx.com/)

I was thrown into this theme, so I don't know what the server aspects are, or if I'm missing some crucial element, from what I can tell I'm doing everything right and it's not working, so I'm thinking it may be a server issue, but then I thought the eot embedded-opentype fix was supposed to take care of that, and then any .htaccess edits I do don't change anything, I'm so lost.

Comment: Seems to be fine? Has this been fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Oswald font, I suggest using the [Font Squirrel Font Face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate your font files and CSS. Select the 'expert' control option and change 'EOT compressed' to 'EOT Lite' ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYJjO.jpg)).

Answer (score 0):

not working in IE9

```
font: 1em/100%  'myfont'
```

working perfectly in IE9

```
font: 1em/100%  myfont
```

It took me a hole day to get this right and it was just a ' matter. I love this things, they make my life happier. :-)